# Model loses its value the second time it is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that calls these two methods.

```
public ActionResult DepthDefinition_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int wellId)
{
    var list = _service.FindBy(x => x.WellId == wellId);

    return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult DepthDefinition_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, DepthDefinition depthDefinition, int wellId)
{
    if (depthDefinition != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        depthDefinition = _service.Insert(depthDefinition);
    }
    return Json(new[] { depthDefinition }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Now, the calling definition looks like this:

```
    .Read(read => read.Action("DepthDefinition_Read", "DepthDefinition",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellId", Model } })))
    .Create(update => update.Action("DepthDefinition_Create", "DepthDefinition",
        new RouteValueDictionary(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "wellId", Model } })))
```

And when I load my view with the grid in it, I do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int wellId)
{
    return PartialView("DepthDefinition", wellId);
}
```

The Read method gets the `wellId` and its value is 1. Everything is sweet and dandy.
I then proceed to create a new row, and click the button, insert my values and click save. Now what happens is that the `wellId` that I try to pass in has magically changed, and is now 0.... well how in the world did that happen? Does my model lose its value?

Anyone who can shed a light on why it forgets its value from the first, to the second call?

Comment: Not sure about it but try putting hidden field in your partial view. @Html.Hidden("wellId", 1)

Comment: I could, but it would sort of defy the whole concept of using a model.. would it not? - and how would i insert it into the grids Create method.....?

Comment: I think that 0 is the default value for an int, when no matching formattribute is found. To ease debugging, change wellId to int? and look if it's hull - if so, it somehow got lost in your view.

Comment: An int cannot be null, so it becomes 0. And yes, it somehow got lost in my view. This far i have come myself. I need someone to explain to me why, because i do not understand why it would just suddenly get lost, for no apparent reason... If i knew why, i could probably fix it ;) And wellId is int... both when sending in to partial view, in the definition of the model, and when recieved by the create method serverside....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted the same question to Telerik. Got a good answer:

http://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket.aspx?threadid=826587